# How to include and use non TS Node modules in my Angular 2 project

Tags: node.js, angular

I just want to use it, I don't care about autocomplete and all the sugar..

In package.json

```
"module-x": "https://github.com/somerepo/module-x"
```

I then try to use it in my app.component.ts

```
import "module-x";
```

and it cannot be found in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 takes JS and TS modules just fine. It will have issues with angular 1 modules however.

My guess is that your module issues are that you never ran "npm install -s" so although the package json still has it, the actual module files were never installed/downloaded.

Do `"npm install -s"` in project folder

and then...

```
import {* or feature name} from "module_x";
```